# Arguments become corrupt when used in pthread_create

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, quicksort

I'm trying to learn multithreading and I thought that parallelizing algorithms would be a good exercise. [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) in particular.

My problem is that arguments become corrupt from calling `pthread_create` to the point of entering the function associated with the call.

My Quicksort function looks like this

```
static void* quick_sort( void* threadData )
{
    struct ThreadData* data = (struct ThreadData*)threadData;

    unsigned pivot_index;

    pthread_mutex_lock( &lock );
        printf( "\nThread %d : Entering quick_sort with low = %d, high = %d ", data->threadID, data->low, data->high );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );

    // No need to sort a vector of zero or one element 
    if ( data->low >= data->high )
            return NULL;


    // Select the pivot value 
    pivot_index = ( data->low + data->high ) / 2;

    // Partition the vector 
    pivot_index = partition( data->collection, data->low, data->high, pivot_index );


    /*              Set thread data                  */
    //-------------------------------------------------
    struct ThreadData left, right;
    left.collection = data->collection;
    left.low    = data->low;
    left.high   = pivot_index - 1;
    left.threadID   = data->threadID;

    right.collection = data->collection;
    right.low    = pivot_index + 1;
    right.high   = data->high;
    right.threadID   = data->threadID;
    //------------------------------------------------


    /* sort the two sub arrays */
    if ( data->low < pivot_index )
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &lock );            // Lock mutex
        if( numRunningThreads < NUM_THREADS )   // Check for an available thread
        {
            // Find available thread index
            int j;
            for( j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++ )
            {
                if( !runningThreads[j] )
                {
                    left.threadID = j;          // threadPool[j] is available
                    runningThreads[j] = true;   // Set thread as running
                    break;
                }
            }
            /* Use mutex lock when incrementing numRunningThreads
               since it is a global variable and shared by all threads */
            numRunningThreads++;

            printf( "\n     Dispatching thread %d -- ", j );
            printf( "low = %d, high = %d, pivot_index = %d, threadID = %d  ---", left.low, left.high, pivot_index, left.threadID );
            printf( "  %d threads running", numRunningThreads );

            pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );

            // Create new thread
            pthread_create( &threadPool[left.threadID], NULL, &quick_sort, (void*)&left );
        }
        else
        {
            // There are NO available threads
            pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );
            quick_sort( (void*)&left ); // Use existing thread
        }
    }

    if ( pivot_index < data->high )
        quick_sort( (void*)&right );

    return NULL;
}
```

**Edit**
The usage of ´pthread_create´ is

```
  pthread_create( &threadPool[left.threadID], NULL, &quick_sort, (void*)&left );
```

The function is initially called from `main`:

```
// Use first thread in threadPool
runningThreads[0] = true;
numRunningThreads++;
pthread_create( &threadPool[0], NULL, &quick_sort, (void*)&threadData );

// Join threads
for( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
{
    if( runningThreads[i] )
    {
        pthread_join( threadPool[i], NULL );

        pthread_mutex_lock( &lock );
            printf( "\nJoining thread %d", i );
            runningThreads[i] = false;
            numRunningThreads--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &lock );
    }
}
```

According to the output the data is corrupt when entering the function

```
Thread 3 : Entering quick_sort with low = -259450448, high = 32567
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please check if the error still appears, when you reduce the `quick_sort` function to just printing the arguments.

Comment: The short version is that your thread refers to memory on another thread's stack. You have no guarantee of that remaining intact once its scope ends. Allocate memory for a copy, or use some synchronization to allow the thread to copy it before it vanishes.

Comment: The `pthread_create()` call and the observed behavior are not sufficient to diagnose the problem.  Unless you present a *complete program* that demonstrates the problem, the best we can do is guess.  Do, however, try to limit what you present to the essentials: an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Extending what @Hasturkun said, where is `threadData` declared and defined? Please refer to this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). More input needed for Johnny5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the thread a automatic variable `left` is defined and initialized:

```
struct ThreadData left, right;
```

then under certain conditions that variable is passed to a newly created thread. This is not done under any kind of locking mechanism:

```
pthread_create( &threadPool[left.threadID], NULL, &quick_sort, (void*)&left );
```

Immediately after creating that thread and passing `left` to it, the current thread can immediately exit, while at the same time the created thread still runs and uses the variable `left`:

```
if ( pivot_index < data->high )
    quick_sort( (void*)&right );

return NULL;
```

then the variable `left` stops existing, while still being used, causing undefined behavior.

Solution is to use allocated variables, i.e. use malloc, pass those variables to the created threads and free them when they are no longer used.